# Is it possible to delete and recreate a table object in VBA without de-referencing the formulas in the workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table object in the sheet which is used by many formulas in my workbook.

The table object is created in a VBA routine.

The issue is any formulas refering to the table get broken if the table is re-created in the VBA routine. Is it possible to avoid this.

For example

```
=SUMIFS(output_dump[Value],output_dump[assetClass],"ML")
```

gets broken when the table is deleted and recreated with the same name during the VBA routine

```
=SUMIFS(#REF!,#REF!,"ML")
```

Is there a way of locking the formulas in the sheet or preventing them from updating during a VBA routine?

Comment: In theory, you could dump all of your worksheet formulas into an array and  then stick them back onto the worksheets after. God knows how slow that would be, I don't even want to guess...

Comment: Yeah, would be nice, I tried turning calculation mode to `xlCalculationManual` but to no avail..

Comment: Can't you just update the table data instead of re-creating it? You could make `.Clear` or similar (I do not know your specific case)

Comment: @RCaetano the number of columns could grow, so maybe this is an issue will try it, thanks

Comment: do you remove the table and recreate, or just refresh the data?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav remove the table, paste an area, convert to table

Comment: Take a look here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598980/deleting-and-reuploading-data-table-without-references-having-ref-issues-excel#51599358

Answer (score 0):

just insert rows in your table and any references of it will be updated to encompass the new data rows range

Option Explicit

```
Sub main()
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set tbl = Worksheets("table").ListObjects("output_dump") '<--| change "table" to your actual worksheet name

    With tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(2) '<-- reference data 2nd row
        .Insert '<-- insert a row -> you'll have a new empty row between data row 1 and 2
        .Offset(-1).Cells(1, 1) = "ML" '<-- fill inserted row row index (.Offset(-1)) first column (.Cells(1, 1))
        .Offset(-1).Cells(1, 2) = 100 '<-- fill inserted row row index (.Offset(-1)) second column (.Cells(1, 2))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @OfficialBenWhite; did you get through it?

Comment: @OfficialBenWhite, it'd be nice and appropriate of you giving feedbacks to people trying at helping you