# Deleting and reuploading data table without references having #REF issues [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, auto-update

I created a VBA script that deletes an existing data table (named Data) and replaces it with a new version (that has the same headers and is named Data). I have a lot of formulas and charts that rely on this table and was wondering how I can keep the references working after changing the table (so that pivot tables, formulas, and array formulas update automatically when I update the Data table).

Below are some pictures of the problems I am running into:

**Pivot tables not updating with new data**
[image: Pivot table not updating average time value]

**Data turning to #REF! after deleting Data table**
[image: Formulas not updating]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely what is happening is that once you delete the table (based on your definition of the problem), the link to the chart is then lost.

Rather than delete the table (as a whole), delete the individual data rows:

```
Sub RemoveTableBodyData()

Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

'Delete Table's Body Data
  If tbl.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Delete
  End If

End Sub
```

from:  [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

This should otherwise keep the table reference intact for the chart.  FYI: because the data has been updated, you may want to make a call out to refresh any dependent pivots and charts, otherwise it may not be clear the data has updated... I might make the call to refresh once after the data set has been cleared, then again after the update... this will make it clear the pivots/charts have been updated.

Good Luck.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. Would it be possible to make it so that the reference is absolute (so that when the table is replaced, as long as the name stays the same, I can then update the data and the pivot tables, charts, and formulas will be referring to the new table)?

Comment: I tried a quick experiment on a table and simple chart, and did some additional checking, too.    In my test I named the table, SAMPTABLE, and used it, as well as the field[name] reference, but it didn't work the absolute table reference remained.  Apparently, the use of table references in charting was conscious decision:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/mrexcels-products-books-cds-podcasts/541307-charts-using-excel-table-columns-data-source.html.  Adding rows (and columns!) to the table automatically updated the chart with no additional work (or brain damage).

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic named range as the pivottable source. Then only remove data below the headers.Don't overwrite or change the headers

Or use your existing table but again keep the headers and only delete rows from beneath (e.g. `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Delete`
) . If you delete the entire table then any dependant formulas will error as the reference is no longer valid. That table no longer exists.

Or have code that creates everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

So, why not change all the formulae to text by using edit/replace "=" with "xyxyxy" and then do whatever with your data as everything is just text.

Once done replace "xyxyxy" with "=" and the formulae work again - works fine with my sheets and I have a LOT of formulae in them.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Do you have the accompanying code?

Comment: Have not done it via vba - but there is no reason why you can't... And, just had a check on the sheets I do that on - they have about 35000 calculation cells sorting data...

Comment: Ok. Figured I would check before I did it. Will try it out now.

Comment: I have faith as it works on mine, but do it on a copy ... I love the word backup...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but a simple solution I found was to change the table reference to use indirect. Example `Table1[Field1]` changes to `indirect("Table1[Field1]")`.